# Mostrar Datos de una petición GET en un SELECT de HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http-get

Necesito mostrar los datos de una tabla dentro de una etiqueta `<select>` de HTML.
La respuesta que obtengo al realizar la petición GET es en formato JSON y es la siugiente:

[image: Respuesta petición GET]

Dentro del select sólo quiero mostrar la provincia. El código javascript que estoy utilizando es:

```
function Solicita_Datos() {
            var dato = document.getElementById('destinoForm').selectedIndex;
            var url = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/destination";
            peticion.onreadystatechange = tratarDestinoForm;
            peticion.open("GET", url, true);
            peticion.send();

        } 

        function tratarDestinoForm() {
            //Se encarga de tratar las respuestas que vienen del servidor
            var respuestaForm;
            if (peticion.readyState == 4) {
                if (peticion.status == 200) {
                    respuesta = JSON.parse(peticion.responseText);
                    RellenaSelect(respuestaForm);
                }  
                else
                    alert("Ocurrio un problema con la URL.");
            }
        }   


        function RellenaSelect(los_datos) {
            var otro_select = document.getElementById('destinoForm');
            otro_select.options.length = los_datos.length;
            for (i = 0; i < los_datos.length; i++) {
                otro_select.options[i].value = los_datos[i].provincia;
                otro_select.options[i].text = los_datos[i].provincia;
            } //for       
        } // de la funcion
```

Y el HTML es:

```
<div id="main">
   <form id ="formRegistro" name="registro" method='get'>

   Introduce Destino: <select name='destino' id='destinoForm' onclick="Solicita_Datos()">
        </select>    
    <br />
    <br />
   </form>
</div>
```

¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que crear las `options` y agregarlas al `select`, de la forma actual estas asignando los valores a `options` que no existen.

```
 function RellenaSelect(los_datos) {
     var otro_select = document.getElementById('destinoForm');

     for (i = 0; i < los_datos.length; i++) {
         var opt = document.createElement('option');
         opt.value = los_datos[i].provincia;
         opt.innerHTML = los_datos[i].provincia;
         otro_select.appendChild(opt);
     }
```

Comment: De esa forma, aparece un error debido a que 'los_datos' is undefined

Comment: Cambia `RellenaSelect(respuestaForm);` por `RellenaSelect(respuesta);`, de esta forma no es nulo.

Comment: Con ese cambio funciona perfectamente.